# Vertex AI - Juypiter Notebook. Error when running 'pip install kfp'

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm having problems running this command in a managed Vertex AI Notebook:
`pip install kfp`

I get the following error:
`ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/six-1.16.0.dist-info/METADATA'`

Which I believe has to do with the MAX_PATH limitation. But I haven't confirmed this.

The same command works on my personal GCP account, but when moving the notebook to my work organization I run into this issue.

Can anyone tell me how to change this limitation in GCP or alternatively point me to another way of resolving this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.